# C/CAPL defining one array from another

Tags: c, arrays, capl

this is my first question here, please notice I'm very new to coding. Quick search doesn't helped me since I think the answer might be too simple.

Im writing some code in CAPL (a CANoe specific language based on C).
Lets have my scenario simplified: I have to read 10 values Input, but I'm just able to read one by a time (due to HW reasons).

My value is stored in a buffer (rsBuf), now I'm trying to define a help-array for everytime I read the value (rsBuf1 ... 10).
At the end I will create another array with added values of rsBuf1 ... rsBuf10.

for every "read-action", I want to define 
rsBuf1 = rsBuf;
rsBuf2 = rsBuf; and so on...

error:  for "rsBuf1 = rsBuf;" Error 1112 at (732,16): operand types are incompatible.
Compilation failed -- 1 errors, 0 warnings

my "real" values:

```
variables
{
byte rsBuf[1024];
byte rsBuf1[1024];
}
```

is there an easy way to do this one-array-from-another? 
I also tried some other notations I found, like rsBuf1 = {rsBuf}, but wasn't helping. Of course I could define 
rsBuf1[1]=rsBuf[1];
...
rsBuf1[1024]=rsBuf[1024];

but that would be a waste of time I guess.
Thanks in advance, cheers Robert

Comment: have you tried `memcpy()` ? :) something along the lines of `memcpy(rsBuf1, rsBuf, 1024);`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just tried http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm:  memcpy(rsBuf1, rsBuf, strlen(rsBuf)+1);
         //  same error: Error 1154 at (732,31): types of parameters do not match.
  Error 1112 at (733,16): operand types are incompatible.  ******************** thanks, now tried with 1024, its working!

Comment: Glad to have helped you with your first question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy arrays through assignment in C, because the syntax does not allow it. The best solution is to use the `memcpy` function.

Alternatively, if it makes sense for the program design, you could put the arrays inside a wrapper struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int array [5];
} array_wrapper_t;

array_wrapper_t this = {1,2,3,4,5};
array_wrapper_t that;
that = this;
```

This should yield identical machine code as a call to `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You can use `memcpy` as follows to copy the entire array:

```
memcpy(rsBuf1, rsBuf, elcount(rsBuf));
```

The following would copy the first four bytes:

```
memcpy(rsBuf1, rsBuf, 4);
```

#### Option 2

Optionally you could define your copy-function, see the `copy_buffer()` implementation:

```
variables
{
  byte rsBuf[1024] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  byte rsBuf1[1024]; 
}

on start
{
  print_buffer(rsBuf, 8);
  print_buffer(rsBuf1, 8);

  copy_buffer(rsBuf1, rsBuf, elcount(rsBuf));

  print_buffer(rsBuf1, 8);
}

void copy_buffer(byte dest[], byte src[], long len)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    dest[i] = src[i];
}

void print_buffer(byte buf[], byte len)
{
  int i;
  writeLineEx(0, 0, ">");
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    writeEx(0, 0, " 0x%02x", buf[i]);
}
```